# Exam Class, "solution" not displaying

Tags: exam

I've been trying to use the below code and anything inside the solution block doesn't show up. Any idea why?

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}{}
\question test q?
\begin{solution}
    test ans
\end{solution}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You need to indicate that you want to pronto the answers, e.g. with `\documentclass[answers]{exam}`.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Ah that fixed it. If you would like to make that an answer so that it's easier to find for other people, I can mark it as solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to indicate that you want to print the answers, e.g. by adding the `answers` key when loading the class, e.g. `\documentclass[answers]{exam}`.

```
\documentclass[answers]{exam}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}{}
\question test q?
\begin{solution}
    test ans
\end{solution}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

There are alternatives, you can also just say `\printanswers`.